# This scala code wouldn't show my result

Tags: scala

I just started writing Scala about a month ago. I however have been writing in Java, Javascript and some others. 
Please I'd need someone to tell me why this code wouldn't display the result of the move(x,y) method. Even though it builds and runs succesfully.

---

```
  class PinPoint(val xc: Int, val yc: Int){
     var x:Int = xc; var y:Int = yc

     def move(dx:Int, dy:Int){
       x = x + dx
       y = y + dy

       println("Position on horizontal axis is " + x);
       print("Position on vertical axis is " + y);
       }
   }


   object Run {
       def main(args: Array[String]) {

          val pos = new PinPoint(20,18);
          println()
          pos.move(5,7);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Works for me. Maybe a problem with (re-)compilation, or you are running an old version? BTW, you should tag this [scala] instead of [functional-programming].

Comment: Thanks. I used scala online compiler which I believe is up to date. Thanks for the info. Now I know the code is ok since you confirmed it working.

Comment: http://scastie.org/9440

Answer (score 0):

Consider also this approach where a new `PinPoint` instance is created each time `move()` is called, namely using (immutable) values instead of (mutable) variables,

```
case class PinPoint(x: Int, y: Int) {

  def move(dx: Int, dy: Int) = PinPoint(x+dx, y+dy)

  override def toString() = 
    s"""|Position on horizontal axis is $x
        |Position on vertical axis is $y""".stripMargin
}


object Run {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val pos = PinPoint(20,18);
    println(pos)

    val shiftedPos = pos.move(5,7);
    println(shiftedPos)
  }
}
```

Method `toString()` delivers a multiline string where class members `x` and `y` have been interpolated.

One way to compile and run it,

```
scalac PinPoint.scala -d PinPoint.jar
scala PinPoint.jar
```

and so

```
Position on horizontal axis is 20
Position on vertical axis is 18
Position on horizontal axis is 25
Position on vertical axis is 25
```

Comment: Awesome. Cool approach. Nice